# MySQL Workbench Freezing when Starting/Stopping Server

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I recently started using MySQL Server and Workbench (both version 8.0), and noticed a strange issue: When I load Workbench, go to Server -> Startup/Shutdown and click "Stop Server", MySQL will freeze. Here's a picture:
[image]

When I press Stop Server, it first gives me a windows prompt about allowing it to make changes, then as you can see it freezes and grays out. The same thing happens if the server is off and I press Start Server.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled everything related to MySQL, cleared MySQL from Program Files & Program Data, and had zero luck. The server does turn on/off from Component Services however, so my temporary solution has been a poorly written powershell script to turn it off and on.

If anyone has a solution for why it won't turn on in Workbench please let me know.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem actually. Did you found any solution ?

Comment: @YoussefSadiki no luck unfortunately. like I said turning it off and on from component services works at least, and you can automate it with powershell / cmd scripts

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The only way to fix the issue is using MySQL Installer (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer). Once you 'Remove' and 'Add', it will work (the DB will not be deleted, so no worries)!

Answer (score 0):

My only solution to the problem was uninstalling 8.0.32, and installing 8.0.11
I haven't tested any other versions.