# MySQL Workbench crash when Starting/Stopping Server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just downloaded the latest version of MySQL Workbench and going to start the server crashes, Any solution?

[image: MySQL Workbench crash]

Comment: yeah it doesn't stop the server, the gui cursor gies to runninf, but nithing happens. i wil let it run for a while. but you can post a bug report and post here the link, so hat others can vote on it

Comment: I understand, but I have to start the server I need to study. How can I do?

Comment: start services(app) on your computer and look for MySQL80, it will be runnign as it is on autostart

Comment: I can't find any mysql in services

Comment: it must be there as your screenshot suggest it is running. have you ordered it by name and looked?

Comment: The screenshot is not mine is the same as the one that says stopped in red to me.

Comment: you have to install mysql server together with the workbench, workbench allone brings no server with him.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and made a post about it here:

[MySQL Workbench Freezing when Starting/Stopping Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758979/mysql-workbench-freezing-when-starting-stopping-server)

Unfortunately no one was able to give a solution to how to do it from workbench.

But luckily you can do it from outside the workbench. Open the "Services" app on your PC (I assume you're using Windows, may be worth clarifying...) look for "MySQL80" (or something similar to that depending on your MySQL version), click it, and use the controls there to start and stop your MySQL server.

This can be automated with a Powershell script as well if you're that lazy like me.

Comment: I can't find any mysql in services

Comment: @Nicolos make sure you're under Services (Local), they should be listed in alphabetical order

Comment: Yes I am in local computer services but mysql does not come out

Comment: have you posted a bug report on  oracles bug tracker?

Comment: Not yet, i need to start the server I need to study.

Comment: you can use dbfiddle to study, but see my comment on your post

Comment: Win+R then `services.msc` is a shortcut. `MySQL80` is what shows for me after installing MySQL with MySQL Installer 8.0.33. Right click -> Stop to stop the MySQL service.

Answer (score 2):

Found how to solve it for myself, hope it will serve others.
When installing workbench it doesn't install the mysql server.
To install it, run mysql installer (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/), you can download the slim web installer.
After launching it, click the 'Add' button on the right, then go to MySql Servers, select the latest server to install and proceed with wizard to set it up and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
The only way to fix the issue is using `MySQL Installer` (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer).
Once you 'Remove' and 'Add', it will work (the DB will not be deleted, so no worries)!

Answer (score 0):

No reinstalling magic worked for me, just got rid of 8.0.32, and installed 8.0.11, works fine now. Haven't tested other versions yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, a syntax error in a `User Snippets` file causes the crash.
Try opening the file and see if there are any redundant newlines, etc., especially at the beginning and the end of the file.
The file location on Windows is as follows:

`C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\snippets`

Answer (score 0):

Just open Mysql installer and reconfigure mysql server again. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for MySql installer and open that[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ehnr.jpg)

2. the reason your database is not working because you dont have mysql server.
3. after opening it, click on "add" then browse for mysql server.
4. select the mysql server that you want to install. Now click on install.
5. After adding that, install it.

if even after not working, then search for Services in your laptop,

1. look for MySql80 then enable it

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to the actual MySQL service being down.

Go to task manager -> Services.
Find MySQL80 service and rightClick -> Start. Will take a few seconds to start.

Now when you connect Workbench, it will successfully connect after the password prompt.

[Task manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoUzZ.png)